# Slicing a string into multiple columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to decipher(reverse engineer) a large amount of canbus messages. I've already filtered on incoming/outcoming and identifier. So now I'm left with an eight byte hexadecimal string. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to slice the string into columns of 1 or 2 characters. So next I can convert all the values to binary.
This is what the first 5 messages look like:

```
       data
5      0087CE5481900307
12     0087CF5481900307
19     0087CF5481900307
26     0087CE5481900307
33     0087CF5481900307
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.str.extractall` and `unstack`:

```
print (df["data"].str.extractall("(\w{2})").unstack())

        0                            
match   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
5      00  87  CE  54  81  90  03  07
12     00  87  CF  54  81  90  03  07
19     00  87  CF  54  81  90  03  07
26     00  87  CE  54  81  90  03  07
33     00  87  CF  54  81  90  03  07
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a function to your serie to convert the string into bytearray:

```
l_val = ["0087CE5481900307",
         "0087CF5481900307",
         "0087CF5481900307",
         "0087CE5481900307",
         "0087CF5481900307"]
serie = pd.Series(data = l_val, index=[5,12,19,26,33])
# Output:
5     0087CE5481900307
12    0087CF5481900307
19    0087CF5481900307
26    0087CE5481900307
33    0087CF5481900307
dtype: object

new_serie = serie.apply(bytearray.fromhex)
new_serie
# Ouptut:
5     [0, 135, 206, 84, 129, 144, 3, 7]
12    [0, 135, 207, 84, 129, 144, 3, 7]
19    [0, 135, 207, 84, 129, 144, 3, 7]
26    [0, 135, 206, 84, 129, 144, 3, 7]
33    [0, 135, 207, 84, 129, 144, 3, 7]
dtype: object

new_serie[5]
# Output:
bytearray(b'\x00\x87\xceT\x81\x90\x03\x07')
```